# Reduce code for lazy loading image

Tags: java, lazy-loading

I have a lot of images to load and I want the loading to be lazy. At this point I wrote a class with all my loaded images.

```
public static ImageIcon binIcon = getBinIcon();
private static ImageIcon getBinIcon() {
    if(binIcon == null) {
        return binIcon = FileManipulation.getImage("img/bin.jpg");
    }
    else {
        return binIcon;
    }
}

public static ImageIcon checkboxIcon = getCheckboxIcon();
private static ImageIcon getCheckboxIcon() {
    if(checkboxIcon == null) {
        return checkboxIcon = FileManipulation.getImage("img/checkbox.png");
    }
    else {
        return checkboxIcon;
    }
}

...
```

Finally I have a lot of duplicate code, I'm looking for a sexy way to reduce it.

Thank you for your ideas !

Comment: Why don't you pass the filename  `"img/checkbox.png"` as an argument to a method `getImageIcon(String filename)`?

Comment: This is quite weird : your accessor methods are private and your variables public. You'd better do the opposite!

Comment: Furthermore, you are not doing any lazy-loading that because you directly instantiate `binIcon `and `checkboxIcon `

Comment: You are right, maybe I should do the opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method receiving the icon to load and the file name :

```
public static ImageIcon checkboxIcon;
public static ImageIcon binIcon;

private static ImageIcon getCheckboxIcon(ImageIcon icon, String fileName) {
    return icon == null ? FileManipulation.getImage(fileName) : icon;
}
```

It will allow you to load the icons this way :

```
binIcon = getCheckboxIcon(binIcon, "img/bin.png");
checkboxIcon = getCheckboxIcon(checkboxIcon, "img/checkbox.png");
```

Comment: I want to load the image only once and here it is reload at every call.

Comment: No the image will be loaded just if the icon you pass as parameter is null, otherwise the method will just returned the already loaded icon.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, you set the value outside of the function

Answer (score 1):

Object oriented simply - a `class LazyImageIcon extends ImageIcon`. Then you could even postpone the reading to the first painting, if given right image size to the constructor.